# What can replace this button RaiseEvent in this scenario?

Tags: c#, wpf, asynchronous

I'm practicing on async programming and tried to make a simple example to clarify my question. This is a demonstration so the aim is not change labels inside the same function but by using two separate functions namely func1 and func2.

So I want to start two async functions func1 and func2  almost at the same time with single click on Button1.

But as you see below in my code, I had to create another button called Button2 and Button2 click event to start func2 at the same with func1:

[image]

```
namespace AsyncSyncCompWPF
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }      
        public async Task<bool> func1()
        {
            for (int i=0; i < 100; i++)
            {
                await Task.Delay(100);
                labelLeft.Content = i.ToString();
            }
            return true;
        }
        public async Task<bool> func2()
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
            {
                await Task.Delay(100);
                labelRight.Content = i.ToString();
            }
            return true;
        }
        private async void Button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Button2.RaiseEvent(new RoutedEventArgs(ButtonBase.ClickEvent));
            await func1();            
        }

        private async void Button2_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            await func2();
        }
    }
}
```

Now instead of creating the button Button2, can I create a method which would do exactly the same thing so I don't have to create an extra button? (Is a delegate needed for that?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your first button, you can invoke `func1` and `func2` as Tasks and then send them to `Task.WhenAll` which will run the tasks, concurrently, to completion:

```cs
Task<bool> f1 = func1();
Task<bool> f2 = func2();

await Task.WhenAll(f1, f2);
```

`Task.WaitAll` will block the UI, while `Task.WhenAll` does not block the UI since it gets awaited. Review [Task.WhenAll](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.whenall?view=net-5.0) to understand how it works.

Since `func1` and `func2` return a `Task`, you do not need to `await` them in the context of creating the `f1` and `f2` variables since you want them both to run at the same time from `Task.WhenAll`. If you did `await` them when creating the variables, then they would run synchronously, one-by-one, and they would be returning a `bool`, not a `Task<bool>`.

Comment: Did you try it? I tried this and labels to not show anything when I click on Button1. Freezes I think.

Comment: You may need to use `await Task.WhenAll(f1, f2)` ?

Comment: Yes that worked. I just tried.

Comment: Is `WhenAll` actually updating the UI every 100ms in each method?

Comment: It seems both labels updates with same number. I also tried to see it with 1 sec delay. It seems it works like the functions are in phase which is good.

Comment: @GNZ - I've updated the answer as well as provided an alternative to updating the UI in WPF, if needed.

Comment: Task.WaitAll still blocks the UI with using Application.Current.Dispatcher.. Can you add how to use Application.Current.Dispatcher as well? Maybe Im doing something wrong. But Task.WaitAll still doesnt work.

Comment: Check the revised answer (and from comments), you need to use `Task.WhenAll`, _NOT_ `Task.WaitAll`. I just tired with a sample WPF app and `Task.WhenAll` updates the UI just fine per the answer, without using the Dispatcher.

Comment: Yes true Task.WhenAll works. I just wanted to point Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke is not necessary with Task.WhenAll. And it doesnt remedy Task.WaitAll. So I was wondeirng why you mentioned Dispatcher.Invoke.

Comment: @GNZ - as I stated clearly in my answer, it's been awhile since I used WPF and said if the UI is still not updating, you may need to use the Dispatcher.

Comment: Okay got it trying to learn async

Comment: In .net async, when you create a Task object, it is by default scheduled to current synchronization context. If the task is created from the UI thread in WPF like click event of a button, the synchronization context is DispatcherSynchronizationContext, which uses the dispatcher to queue work to the UI thread. So in your case there is no need to explicitly use the Dispatcher as it already happens for you when the task is created. Conversely, if the task is created in a non-UI thread, it is likely you need to use the Dispatcher to queue your UI manipulation work to the UI thread.